# can't send mail plesk 12

Tags: email, plesk

I can't send mail of my domains in plesk (it worked before)
I don't know how this could happpen.

i can logininto the webmail but whenever i try to send a message it keeps loading and nothing happens.

when i try to login on outlook i get the message **can't connect to outgoing smtp email server**

so i assume there is something wrong with the outgoing mail.

when i try to send a mail to the domain from gmail i get no error back but it won't display in the inbox.

it used to work and i don't know how i can fix this i did some research but nothing helped.

like open smtp in iptables

hope you guys can help me cause i got some angry customers haha

Comment: This is most likely not a programming problem.  Please read the documentation on what makes for an appropriate question.

Comment: fixed by ~# /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/mchk --with-spam